Why increasing the "chunk size" tends to worsen the performance of this program?
I have this code which I developed for some test suite involving pdf files. Now while running this code I encountered a strange behaviour . You see I am generating a dummy pdf file of roughly 1MB the dummy data is created by dummyTxt() to which I need to tell how much KB worth of text I need to generate, given by the KB_MULTIPLIER. The strange thing I notice is the higher the KB_MULTIPLIER the worst is the runtime I am curious as to what could be the underlying issue since common sense tells the more data you generate in bulk the faster something would be
const fs = require('fs');
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

const KB_MULTIPLIER = 1 // This is the thing I am referring to


function createPDF(filePath, targetSizeInBytes) {
    const doc = new PDFDocument();

    const stream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
    doc.pipe(stream);

    let fileSize = 0;

    // Generate random text and write to the pdf file
    while (fileSize < targetSizeInBytes) {
        const text = dummyTxt(1024 * KB_MULTIPLIER);
        doc.text(text);
        fileSize += Buffer.byteLength(text, 'utf-8');
    }

    doc.end();
}

const filePath = 'fake.pdf';
const targetSizeInBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024; // 1 MB

const startedOn = new Date().getTime();
createPDF(filePath, targetSizeInBytes);
const endedOn = new Date().getTime();
const totalTimeTaken = (endedOn - startedOn)/1000;
console.log('Took '+totalTimeTaken + ' secs.');

This just a helper which generates a bunch of random text
function dummyTxt(length) {
    const chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    let text = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        text += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length));
    }
    return text;
}


Here are some test runs

KB_MULTIPLIER = 1
Took 7.491 secs.


KB_MULTIPLIER = 2
Took 9.627 secs.


KB_MULTIPLIER = 3
Took 12.116 secs.


KB_MULTIPLIER = 4
Took 15.173 secs.


KB_MULTIPLIER = 5
Took 18.013 secs.


KB_MULTIPLIER = 10
Took 32.42 secs.

